# How to make a recursive tuple to describe a logical operator?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to describe the next type without manual description of all cases for a different number of arguments?

```
type Operator = '&&'|'||'
type Logical<T> = (
  | [Expression<T>, Operator, Expression<T> ] 
  | [Expression<T>, Operator, Expression<T>, Operator, Expression<T> ]
  | [Expression<T>, Operator, Expression<T>, Operator, Expression<T>, Operator, Expression<T> ]
  | ...
)
```

Valid type values:

```
find([['id', '=', 10], '&&', ['type', '=', 'animal']])
find([['id', '=', 10], '&&', ['type', '=', 'human'], '&&', ['age', '>=', '40']])
```

Type error in case:

```
find([['id', '=', 10], ['type', '=', 'animal']])
find([['id', '=', 10], '&&', ['type', '=', 'human'], ['age', '>=', '40']])
find([['id', '=', 10], ['type', '=', 'human'], ['age', '>=', '40']])
```

Comment: That's going to be a _very_ hard thing for Typescript to strictly type. It might be possible, but it'll will involve some crazy cryptic generics, no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
// The type of an array's elements
type ArrayType<T extends readonly unknown[]> = T extends readonly (infer U)[] ? U : never
// An array with at least 3 elements
type AtLeast3<T> = readonly [T, T, T, ...T[]]
// Enforces that T's last element is U
type EnforceLastEl<T, U> = T extends readonly [...unknown[], U] ? T : never

// Checks if T starts with A, and then recurses
type AltArr1<T extends readonly unknown[], A, B, InitialValue> =
  T extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
    ? Head extends A
      // Check if the rest starts with B
      ? AltArr2<Tail, A, B, InitialValue>
      // Invalid type
      : never
    // Empty array (we are done)
    : InitialValue

// Same as Alt1 except it checks if T starts with B
type AltArr2<T extends readonly unknown[], A, B, InitialValue> =
T extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
    ? Head extends B
      ? AltArr1<Tail, A, B, InitialValue>
      : never
    : InitialValue

// Enforces an array alternates between A and B and also ends with the first value (A)
type AltArr<T extends AtLeast3<unknown>, A, B> = EnforceLastEl<AltArr1<T, A, B, T>, A>

// Actual stuff specific to Logical

// Because you didn't provide the definition of Expression, I'm not sure if it
// will work with the actual definition
type Expression<T> = T

type LogicalInput<T> = Expression<T> | Operator
type LogicalInputType<T extends LogicalInput<unknown>> =
  T extends LogicalInput<infer U> ? U : never

type Logical<T extends AtLeast3<LogicalInput<unknown>>> =
  AltArr<T, Expression<LogicalInputType<ArrayType<T>>>, Operator>

declare const find: <T extends AtLeast3<LogicalInput<unknown>>>(
  ...args: Logical<T> extends never
    // If T isn't valid, Logical<T> will be never, so don't accept anything
    ? [never]
    // T is valid, accept the argument
    : [expr: T]
) => void

// Errors
find([1])
find([1, '&&'])
find([1, '&&', 2, '||'])
find(['&&', 1, '||'])

// This doesn't work, unfortunately
find([1, '&&', 2])

// Works
find([1, '&&', 2] as const)
find([1, '&&', 2, '||', 3] as const)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-S1nnAYYNhuNTzN1h9VqNFdA2pUM9SPHlQCbGMW3jQws1CcJcxBK1G2jWNW3bMFDmOWZsASJJsHJDwcAWXCACNoDgSsGE4PCsS5OjCLIVBKHNBc0lgdBnEJTJU3PJwOHrZcA0pWlN3pCpqlWOoWS+QxwJubDpmgU5cnOfgRMIGkek5Y8IHkzg4LBDgpjgZRhRnZR0EwMgUCmOFnCmeAWMqVAAHNHOFUFlwAeRQIg4EmUxQBIAAyUKSFAAAfEKoqikgwS5O0sGUIlQAQVBlFAcR0xwEhMiQfBUEidNYA47LoC4tD5FADADmEQrZjIZx5D5EhaHCVBMjIAlYEdVIwRSKgqBRSY1BRVJ0nKrBTPMkbxEq1xBXkElYFGBqXWa+R6mC8BvP2VyPKmYV+SQZQ4B2sx1sasgtpwHaYr8jwFkmVbQEOzyqFO87eBQMSbwoD7jq+nAzou2SdEMKUZWvLdAfcz7vou19vGMIIvAQoEYjeoHhX+uHOCqGo4DqXGQbB-gIZwKHoaA0SemuzaWvusmkd+gRKR4Ph6ihzonoCyYjIWqYqGrUApnkV0qvEMJ8YkonpP4VnQfOyn9zkqHHEtN5EjcsgwjJnbxPNLHkKTMBeWnbY8t4tMn3ehHgZ2oaRooxDgU6ZjsvkfLsCmYdMlwBA0lcNzEyCXRTc-a0wCEbZQD49MMX96AR2m-A3OUYo4AbUBdDuQqwnAYYfFMYxIlQdMOzGQhJhYaXHF0Kl9HrBum86MKIpb5g26pDvwpITogw7uKSG7tvO8H0A+9i+Lu7BKB47kWYbdG-A1E6VQjg9VRSMUHvXHERuZ8nof57iAB1Mb68P4-+4is++3FyW4Fb2-25Cgeh5H+LOjyP4cjPxwLkesQA)

Comment: Thank you very much) I will continue to experiment using your example